# Change the button text AFTER loading the file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button called "**Load completely...**" and want I want to do is, when I click it, change the button text to "**Loading...**", then load the include file and **only after** the file has been loaded completely, then set the button css to `display:none`. My JS code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var change = document.getElementsByClassName(".load-completely");

  $(".load-completely").click(function(){

    if (change.innerHTML == "Load completely...") {

      change.innerHTML = "Loading...";

      $(".remaining").load('includes/LOAD.php');

      $('.load-completely').css("display", "none");

    }

  });

});
```

And my button code is:

```
<div class="col-12 text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm load-completely">Load completely...</button>
</div>

<div class="remaining col-12"></div>
```

When I click the button, it loads the file correctly but doesn’t change the button text before it nor hides the button.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't put the dot at the beginning of the class when calling `getElementsByClassName`. And it returns a collection, not a single element, so you need to index it. Why don't you just use jQuery `$(".load-completely").html()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback function for the jQuery `.load` function to hide the button.

There a few problems with your code:

When getting elements by class name, you do not need the dot in front of the class name; the argument should just be the name of the class. Also, `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names, so you need to get the first element with the class using `document.getElementsByClassName("load-completely")[0]`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var change = document.getElementsByClassName("load-completely")[0];

  $(".load-completely").click(function(){

    if (change.innerHTML == "Load completely...") {

      change.innerHTML = "Loading...";

      $(".remaining").load('https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName', function(){
           $('.load-completely').css("display", "none");
      });

    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm load-completely">Load completely...</button>
</div>

<div class="remaining col-12"></div>
```

Comment: @MARWAN No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Several problems:

1. When you call `document.getElementsByClassName()`, the argument should just be the class, without a dot at the beginning.
2. It returns a collection, not a single element, so you need to index it if you want to do anything with the element.
3. You're hiding the loader immediately, not waiting for `.load()` to complete. You should hide it in the callback function of `.load()`.

You can solve the first two problems by using jQuery instead of the raw JS function, or you could use `document.querySelector()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".load-completely").click(function() {
    if ($(this).html() == "Load completely...") {
      $(this).html("Loading...").show();
      $(".remaining").load('includes/LOAD.php', function() {
        $(".load-completely").html("Load completely...").hide();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yep, you were correct. I was accessing the HTML element incorrectly. I changed it as per recommended and it worked! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous. That means that the code that comes after will be run immediately and will not wait for it to complete loading.

To fix this, use the callback provided by the function to run code *after* it has finished loading:

```
$(".remaining").load('includes/LOAD.php', {}, function() {
  $('.load-completely').css("display", "none");
});
```

---

Also, @Barmar's right: you are accessing the HTML element incorrectly. This should work:

```
var change = document.getElementsByClassName("load-completely")[0];
```

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. Thanks a lot!